# Python - 'too many values to unpack', and 'list has no attribute 'iteritems''

Tags: python

I am trying to compare two strings: `devLine` and `fin_h`. 
When I split the words in both strings and iterate over words in both strings, I keep getting the error `too many values to unpack`.

If I add `iteritems()` like other SO posts mention, then, I get this error: `list has no attribute 'iteritems'`.

The strings are:

`Rob car Mary bike George House Jerry Condo`

`Rob car Mary dc   George dc    Jerry dc`

I want to check if the word in string1 matches the word in string2. The words I want to compare are the alternate words such as `car`, `bike`, `house`, `condo`. I want to compare those words with `car`, `dc`, `dc`, `dc`.  If the words are equal, then print `true` or else, it is `false`. If the word tuple is `(bike, dc)`, then still print out true because `dc` signifies any value that can be accepted as an input.

My code looks like this:

```
def compareLines(devLine, final_hypoth):

devSplit = devLine.split()
hypSplit = final_hypoth.split()

for word in hypSplit.iteritems():

      #if hword  != "?":
           print word
```

I had also tried using the `zip()` function because it seemed more pythonic to use it:

```
def compareLines(devLine, final_hypoth):
    devSplit = devLine.split()
    hypSplit = final_hypoth.split()

    wordSet = [" ".join(tup for tup in zip(devSplit[1::2], hypSplit[1::2])]

    # what to do next?
```

This prints out the odd words in both strings together in an array like `(car, car)`, `(bike dc)`, `(house dc)`, `(condo, dc)`. However, how do I compare both of these values? This way seems easier to print out either `true` or `false` if the two words are equal or if the two comparisons include a `dc`.

Comment: `iteritems()` is a `dict` method, that returns a `(key, value)` tuple iterable. A `list` object is already iterable for its items, just do `for word in hypSplit`, no `iteritems()`

Answer (score 1):

Loop over pairs of words with `zip`:

```
for word1, word2 in zip(devSplit[1::2], hypSplit[1::2]):
    if word1 == word2 or word2 == 'dc':
        print 'true'
    else:
        print 'false'
```

Note that printing `true` or `false` for each pair might not be the most useful behavior. You might want to only print a single value summarizing whether all pairs matched, or you might want to create a list of boolean comparison values, or you might want to do something else.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to compare the values between all the pairs of words, and if the `car` matches `car` or `bike` matches `dc` (like in the code), print `true` or `false` only once. How do I do that?

Comment: @Eagle: Depends on whether you need all to match or just one pair. Loop through the words and find whether all/any pairs match, then print `true` or `false`. You can use the `any` or `all` functions to help with that.